# Simulating sms style typing using keypress

Tags: c#, keypress

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to simulate sms style typing using keypress on the number pad?

I can get each number to print out a letter but am unsure of how to get my program to treat a number of keypresses on the same key as the same 'event' (i.e. scrolling through several letters if the key is pressed again within a period of (for example) 2 seconds).

I have looked up multiple keypresses but always come up with key combinations (ctrl, alt, delete etc).

Comment: I take it you mean the standard phone-style keypad, where you press a key a few times to get a different letter? Is this a system wide thing, or just for your application?

Comment: Just for my application, it's a simple phone network simulator for a project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to store the available combinations:

```
    static char[] num1 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', '1' };
    static char[] num2 = { 'D', 'E', 'F', '2' };
    // etc...
```

And then we make a dictionary of the combinations, mapped to the right key character that produces them:

```
    Dictionary<char, char[]> map = new Dictionary<char, char[]>()
    {
        {'1', num1},
        {'2', num2} 
    };
```

Some variables to keep track:

```
    char[] curr = null;
    char currChar = '-';
    int index = 0;
```

A printing function:

```
    void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(curr[index]);
    }
```

And the logic:

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(e.KeyChar))
        {
            if (curr == null || e.KeyChar != currChar)
            {
                curr = map[e.KeyChar];
                index = 0;
                currChar = e.KeyChar;
                Print();
            }
            else
            {
                ++index;
                if (index == curr.Length)
                    index = 0;
                Print();
            }
        }
    }
```

The logic basically checks to make sure our keymap contains the keycode in question.  If we're not tracking anything, or if it's different to the one we're currently tracking, use that particular map and the first index.

Otherwise, if it's a repeat key-press, increase the index (looping back to the beginning if we pass the end).

Comment: What about the last keypress? You need a timeout of some sort, or confirm with Enter...

Comment: @Moo-Juice Would it be simple thing to add a timer to the logic to automatically go back to the beggining and print current letter if more than 2 seconds pass without a further keypress?

Comment: @thijs, I didn't want to write the whole thing for him, but just give him a starting point to work from.  There are lots of things to add to this, this example merely outputs the characters as they are cycled.  It's pretty trivial to add them to a string on a timeout (at which point we'd reset what char array/index etc)

Answer (score 5):

You need a state-machine and count the number of presses on each key to determine the letter. Then pass these letters on (using events) to the rest of your app.

Ps. did you notice that the numbers on a numeric keypad are in a different order than on a phone? (789 are the top row on a keyboard and the bottom row on a phone)

Comment: I didn't notice actually, now I need to figure out whether to map them numerically or physically :)