# Stop text being written to screen

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I have a routine whereby I use the keypad to write text to the screen in the same manner as the sms functionality on a mobile phone (multiple key strokes to loop through letters) thanks to an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900597/simulate-sms-style-typing-using-keypress-c-sharp) for helping me.

The problem I have now is that the number also gets printed alongside the letter (1's for abc, 2's for def...etc)

How can I disable the key's original keypress function whilst maintaining my own?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the question you referenced you are probably subscribing to the `KeyPress` event. Set the `e.Handled` flag to *true* in that event.